# MS Graph User Delta query C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

When I make a request to the MS Graph user delta endpoint with the C# API I am returned a list of User objects each User object has an AdditionalData property that is a Dictionary. When a user has been removed that dictionary contains an entry with a key that is "@removed" according to the MS documentation https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview.

In the case where the user has been updated in other ways this dictionary contains keys that are the names of other fields on the User object such as preferredLanguage and givenName.

Is this dictionary a complete list of all the fields that have been updated? If not, what are these entries used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User object in the SDK has some explicitly named properties (not in the dictionary) such as DisplayName which will be populated if the property changed. The dictionary contains changed properties which the version of the SDK is not aware of. Additional properties are often links.